# Texture appears stretched on extruded sections of mesh

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a maze game in blender and to make the maze I subdivided a cube I flattened out and then selected some parts, extruded it, and raised it up. But, when I put in the texture, it didn't really work (see images). The walls were just lines. I really need to know how to fix that, even if it means that I don't see the texture the right way on the top. I just need the walls to look nice on the inside.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This can happen for several reasons, the most common being that you modified the mesh *after* initially adding the texture, hence the stretched look. A simple fix is to just unwrap the model *again*.

The fastest way to get a good result with a generic box model like that is to press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Cube Projection* or *Smart UV Project* depending on how tiled you want certain subdivided parts to look (can read more and experiment with the unwrapping types [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping)).

### Extrusions after adding texture

[image]

### Extrusions after *correcting* using cube projection unwrapping

[image]

### Extrusions after *correcting* using smart uv project

[image]

Comment: I went into edit mode with the terrain selected, and I pressed U and chose the smart UV projection, and it did nothing.

Comment: @JudeNelson Is the image open in the uv editor and assigned to the mesh? Also did you select everything with `A`.

Comment: @JudeNelson Your view should look something like this http://i.imgur.com/i3EQQ6A.png

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having problems with the unwrapping, this worked for me too:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWC7Ki7MNEw

Edit Mode > Options > Correct Face Attributes > then extrude

Answer (score 0):

That's just how texture mapping works.

There's a square texture map, and then there's geometry coming off of it with no kind of seams to govern how it's lined up with the texture. It's taking the pixels on the edge and stretching them out infinitely because sides occupy literally no space.

I'm sure you've figured this out years later, but for anyone else looking this is essentially what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the original user was asking about a uv texture, but this was showing up under search results for me under procedural.

Applying location, rotation, and scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>) fixed my problem.

Answer (score -2):

For me, you can apply location, rotation and scale, after it unwrap again.